# How can i access a textEditingController created in another file in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two files. File 1 has a `nameController` and file2 has `emailController` and `passwordController`.
I want to access the `nameController` from file1 in file2 which has the `.registerUsingEmailPassword()` method .

file1

```
class UserName extends StatefulWidget {
const UserName({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<UserName> createState() => _UserNameState();
}
  final _registerFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _nameTextController = TextEditingController();
  ...
Form(
   key: _registerFormKey,
    child:  TextFormField(
    controller: _nameTextController, 
  ..
  )); 
                 

 }
```

file2

```
  class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
    const SignUp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    @override
    State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
    }

   class _MyEmailState extends State<SignUp> {  

   final _regFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
   final _emailController = TextEditingController();
   final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
   ...
     if (_regFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
     User? user = await FireAuth.registerUsingEmailPassword(
      name: _nameTextController.text, // I want to access this controller from 
      file1 
       email: _emailTextController.text, 
      password:_passwordTextController.text,
     );

 }
 
 }
```

Can somebody help please.

Comment: little information, the number of files doesn't matter, I need to know the connection between these two widgets, is it parent/child or is it two different routes, is there another route between them or adjacent, etc... because there are so many There are many different ways to deal with your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be going from **file 1** to **file 2** through navigator, pass the data from **nameController** as an argument to the Navigator like,

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('file2Route', arguments:nameController.text);
```

Get the text in **file2** as

```
var nameText = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as String;
```

Then simply use the nameText in **registerUsingEmailPassword()** method.

If this is not the case, please do specify.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

```
class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
final TextEditingController nameController; // pass via constructor
  const SignUp({Key? key,required TextEditingController nameController}) : super(key: key);
@override
State<SignUp> createState() => _SignUpState();
}
```

then use in build like this

```
 if (_regFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
 User? user = await FireAuth.registerUsingEmailPassword(
  name: widget.nameController.text, // use like this
   email: _emailTextController.text, 
  password:_passwordTextController.text,
 );
```